# Alert dialog never shows escape characters in asp.net ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I'm working on ASP.NET AJAX Web Application.

As part of the requirement, I need to show message to the end user with the uploaded file location. Everything is fine, but the alert message never shows "`/`" symbols in the path.

For the path: `\\shrestasoft\intranet\CorrectionReports\ReportsWithAccount\CorrectionReportWithAccount-Dec-22-2021-12-31-36-PM.xlsx`

Below is how my alert dialog is displaying:

```
\shrestasoftintranetCorrectionReportsReportsWithAccountCorrectionReportWithAccount-Dec-22-2021-12-31-36-PM.xlsx
```

[image]

I've written the below code:

```
    public static void ShowAlertWithFileLocation(object sender, string message)
    {
        message = "alert('" + message + "');";
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock((sender as Control), typeof(ScriptManager), "alert", message, true);
    }
```

I've tried to use `HtmlUtility.HtmlEncode()` method, but that did not work for me. Can someone suggest how can I get the appropriate filename with path?

Answer (score 0):

The \ is considered a escape car. But in place of ' use ` and String.raw

eg this:

```
 message = "alert(String.raw`" + message + "`);";
```

note carefull - there is no () for String.raw - and you use ` and not '

So, you use the ` that left to 1 key on most keyboards.

eg:

```
 var s = String.raw`power\weight`
 alert(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple, but took more time for me to arrive to this conclusion. We just need to use `new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(message);` method.

Below is my modified code:

```
    public static void ShowAlertWithFileLocation(object sender, string message)
    {
        message = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(message);
        message = "alert('" + message + "');";
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock((sender as Control), typeof(ScriptManager), "alert", message, true);
    }
```